# UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification doesn't work while device is on table?

Tags: iphone, uidevice

Hi there i have a problem,
In my `AppDelegate` i have used method `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` to start notify me when device starts rotating.
It works fine if i hand-held my ipad but when it is kept on table it doesn't work as expected.
it fires `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown` notification.
Also this notification gets started after UI launches not on splash screen.

following is my code:

```
if([[[PulseUIFactory Factory] GetUICreator] IsIPad])
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }
     current device stars giving proper values.
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

then some where i launches my UI as

```
[self Launch_UI];
```

but notification starts responding after `[self Launch_UI];` call even if notification is registered before its call...

Please any help is appreciable!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you place your device on a table, `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` will return `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp`. Then if your device remains sitting on the table face up, it doesn't matter how you rotate it on the table, the current device orientation will still be `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp`.

If the device has issues determining the orientation, you may get `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`. See [this](http://the.ichibod.com/kiji/how-to-handle-device-rotation-for-uiviews-in-ios) tutorial on how to handle device rotation using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.

Regarding your notification only firing after the UI is loaded, the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` will only fire when the device is rotated. So if you are not rotating your device until after the UI loads, you wont get a notification. If this is not the cause of the issue, I'd have to see more of your code to have a better idea of what is going on.